# Creating custom instantiation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to instantiate an object in a custom form, something like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

class instance:

  def custom_instanciation(self, estimator=None):
    estimator1 = estimator
    print(estimator1)
    print(type(estimator1))

    estimator2 = f"{estimator}"
    print(estimator1)
    print(type(estimator1))

    estimator3 = LinearRegression()
    print(estimator3)
    print(type(estimator3))
```

**Input:**

```
i = instance()
i.custom_instanciation(estimator="LinearRegression()")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
LinearRegression()
<class 'str'>
LinearRegression()
<class 'str'>
LinearRegression()
<class 'sklearn.linear_model._base.LinearRegression'>
```

See that only in the last case it works, where, I'm not using what was passed to the method - "LinearRegression"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getattr()` function and the name of your module obtained from the `sys` library to achieve that:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
import sys

class instance:

  def custom_instanciation(self, estimator=None):
    estimator1 = estimator
    print(estimator1)
    print(type(estimator1))

i = instance()
i.custom_instanciation(estimator=getattr(sys.modules[__name__], "LinearRegression"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to pass `LinearRegression` itself, not a string, as the argument, and let the method call whatever class is passed.

```
def custom_instantation(self, estimator_class):
    estimator = estimator_class()
```

Then

```
i = instance()
i.custom_instanciation(estimator=LinearRegression)
```

Comment: It was just that? Thanks, it worked the way I wanted.